# Temperatures at extreme densities

Tags: thermodynamics, cosmology, black-holes, singularities

Cosmology (and astrophysics) talk about the "initial singularity" (IS, became the big bang) and "black hole singularities" (BS, inside black holes), and these appear to be quite different: The IS is described as having **zero volume and infinitely high temperature and density**, whereas the BS is likewise zero volume and infinite density, but with a **temperature close to 0 K**. (Personally, I suspect that both the IS and the BS equations suffer from a division be zero error (density = mass/volume, and in both cases the volume is zero (well so they say...)).  My question is:

**If there is infinite density, how can there be any room for thermal activity (temperature)**, let alone **infinitely high** temperature? Shouldn't the IS be stone cold, just like the BS? The BS case seems more reasonable, other than the difficulty I have trying to grasp "infinite mass in zero volume".

Comment: A singularity means a point where Physics fails, so I wouldn't worry about what happens there.

Comment: This is another example of confusing the asymptotic limit of a function with what happens (or doesn't) at the limit point itself.

Comment: ^ What they said. General relativity breaks down on small scales (approx. below Planck length) and quantum effects become important. To figure out what happens on these scales, we need at least a quantum theory of gravity. As a general rule: whenever you get infinity out of a physical theory, it's usually an indicator that this theory is no longer valid in the given circumstances and you need some deeper understanding.

Comment: confusing comment system...

Comment: Well if that is so, Carl Witthoft, would you mind deconfusing me, by telling me what happens (or doesn't) at the limit point?

Comment: Singularities are not described as zero volume... In fact they are not part of spacetime.

Answer (score 4):

It's important to appreciate that when you talk about a singularity at the Big Bang or the centre of a black hole you are really referring to a singularity in a particular mathematical model.

A black hole (usually) means the [Schwarzschild metric](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarzschild_metric), and the equations that describe this become singular at $r = 0$.

The Big bang means the [FLRW metric](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friedmann-Lema%C3%AEtre-Robertson-Walker_metric), and the equations that describe this become singular at $t = 0$.

Note that in both cases these are [mathematical singularities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_singularity) and their relevance to physics is not clear. Most of us believe that the appearance of a singularity means you have pushed your mathematical model beyond the region where it's a good description of the universe, and therefore that the singularity isn't physically meaningful. It's generally believed that in both cases quantum mechanics will become important at scales around the Planck length and this will prevent the singularity from forming. Since we have no theory of quantum gravity we don't know how this will happen.

To return to your original question, the two singularities are indeed very different but that's expected because they occur in two very different mathematical models and there is no reason why they should behave in the same way. In particular the Schwarzschild metric is time independant so it isn't clear to me that *temperature* has any meaning when applied to it.

Comment: I very much appreciate your comments (thanks!), but it looks as if my question was missed:

In the IS, if density is infinite, how can there be any room for thermal activity (even infinite ditto!)?

It appears to make sense that "black holes" have extremely low temperatures (0 K to many orders of magnitude precision (for that same reason? No room for "heat" (molecular motion))